# Alternative to visibility:collapse not working on IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css, html-table, visibility

The following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<STYLE type="text/css"> 
tr.cccc {
visibility: collapse;
}
</STYLE>
<BODY>
<TABLE border="1">
<TR class="cccc">
<TD>one</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

works only in Firefox. IE always displays the row, and Chrome hides the row but showing its vertical space.
So, how can I hide completely a row using only CSS?

Comment: Have you tried "`display: none;`"?

Comment: It is a little late but you can get it to work on Chrome [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807564/hiding-a-tr-while-still-involving-it-in-width-calculations/25807729#25807729)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use
  *display: none*

instead of 
  *visibility: collapse*

It works for me to hide the dojo tree grid summary row in IE6 & Google Chrome

Comment: Unfortunately, `display: none;` also causes the rows and cells to be ignored for purposes of computing rowspan and colspan in at least a few browsers, causing table layouts with rowspan and colspan to go all wonky.

Comment: Will setting visibilty to visable make it appear?  Or will I have to get rid of the display thing as well.

Comment: visibility: visible  is working for me

Answer (score 2):

```
visibility: collapse
```

was implemented in IE8

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531180%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`visibility: collapse` does not work in IE. [Source](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns.html#visibility) seems you will need to use `hidden` instead for IE. See the linked page for details.

> However, the specification clearly states that in the case of columns, only collapse is a valid value. collapse is supported only by Firefox. Since Explorer Windows supports all style declarations on columns anyway, it also supports visibility: hidden.

Also, it doesn't hurt to give the construct a complete HTML structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC 
 "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<STYLE type="text/css"> 
 ....
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
...
```

Comment: I already know hidden value of visibility property. Hidden is not the right solution to my problem. I want the row completely disappears: that is, it hasn't to show a blank space. 
Hidden hides data, BUT retains the vertical space. Collapse hides the data AND remove the space taken by the row, as if it was not there at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is outdated, but you could use innerHTML to rewrite the parts that you want to be "gone."

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems `visibility: collapse` can be used in IE as well. I am using it and it is working in both IE and Firefox. Dont know about other browsers apart from these two.

I have done the following:

HTML:

`<table class="intValidationTable">`

`<tr class="rangeTR" style="visibility: collapse;">`

`<tr class="listTR" style="visibility: collapse;">`

Javascript + Jquery:

`var rows = $('table.intValidationTable tr');`

`var rangeTR = rows.filter('.rangeTR');`

`var listTR = rows.filter('.listTR');`

`rangeTR.css("visibility", "visible");`

`listTR.css("visibility", "collapse");`

This should work!

Answer (score 0):

visibility: collapse; in a tr and td   for me is just hiding the data but still taking up vertical space in Safari in 2020. Works fine in chrome (row and column widths still ok but vertical space is gone)