# Hiding a <tr>, while still involving it in width calculations

Tags: html, css, html-table

There are search results stored in a table like the one below:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Column One</td>
            <td>Column Two</td>
            <td>Column Three</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The actual table contains much more data (both in columns and rows) and is fluid width. Since the data is variable, I would like the `table-layout` to remain `auto`, because it handles autoresizing (which would be expensive and complicated to do in javascript for say 1,000 rows).

This table is also filtered by a live search widget which hides rows that do not match the query by adding `display: none;`. However, I have found that this often causes the column widths to be recalculated (often causing some jarring jumps in column width). This makes sense, given that rows are likely only included calculations if they have `display: table-row;`. But this is not the behavior I am after.

**Is it possible to hide a `<tr>` from view, but still have it included in column widths calculations done (on resize, for example) by the browser on a table with `table-layout: auto;`?**

I've tried setting `height: 0;` (and `max-height: 0;`), but have learned from [other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147850/force-tr-height-with-css) that this does not work because of `display: table-cell;`. Similarly, Setting `line-height: 0;` failed, but I figured it would since a few of my columns have block content.

I've also considered explicitly setting widths on the `<td>`s, but then this makes keeping the table fluid (I would have to remove the explicit widths on resize, which could cause width jumps, and wouldn't work unless all of the rows were visible and included in the browser's table resize calculation).

**Edit:** To clarify, by hide from view I mean hide as in the sense of `display: none;`, not `visibility: hidden;`. The latter of which would work if the element did not retain it's original height when hidden, but unfortunately this is not the case.

*Note: I know that upon first glance this appears to be a pretty narrowly applicable question, but I believe that this could be a common use case. As such, I've bolded the most applicable part (read: most important) of the question. The rest (which is slightly specific to me) is more explanatory than anything else.*

Comment: Usually temporarily showing it before calculations and then hiding it again once you're done should do the trick, as hidden objects don't get any CSS values. So, first put its display to block (or inline-cell, or whatever), then return to display none usually does the trick for me. If your calculations are fast, theres no flash.

Comment: Try `max-height`. Just a guess.

Comment: @torazaburo That's an interesting idea. Unfortunately, it suffers from the same issue that setting the height of a table row has. I've tried it with a combination of `height`, `visibility: hidden;`, and `overflow: hidden;` to no avail.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you are looking for [`visibility: collapse;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#visibility) declaration:

> **[17.5.5 Dynamic row and column effects](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#dynamic-effects)**
>
> The `visibility` property takes the value `collapse` for row, row
>   group, column, and column group elements. This value causes the entire
>   row or column to be removed from the display, and the space normally
>   taken up by the row or column to be made available for other content.
>   Contents of spanned rows and columns that intersect the collapsed
>   column or row are clipped. The suppression of the row or column,
>   **however, does not otherwise affect the layout of the table.** This
>   allows dynamic effects to remove table rows or columns without forcing
>   a re-layout of the table in order to account for the potential change
>   in column constraints.

However it seems this is buggy on some of web browsers. The [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility#Notes):

> The support for `visibility:collapse` is missing or partially incorrect
>   in some modern browsers. In many cases it may not be correctly treated
>   like `visibility:hidden` on elements other than table rows and columns.

Unfortunately it acts as `visibility: hidden` on Chrome37: **[Demo Here](http://jsbin.com/biqupu/1/edit)**.

But fortunately, you can fake the effect by [`line-height: 0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) declaration:

**[Updated Demo](http://jsbin.com/biqupu/2/edit)**

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: collapse;
  line-height: 0; /* Set the height of the line box to 0
                     in order to remove the occupied space */
}
```

Comment: +1 this is exactly what I'm looking for. If only Chrome supported a property value that IE8 supports! I wonder if there is a polyfill or other workaround for this.

Comment: That solves it! I have a few rows with block content, but collapsing them is just a matter of making them `height:0;`. This indeed collapses the row! Thank you!

Comment: When there's a border, even if it is collapsed, there's still padding visible and border is not collapsed. I can set padding to 0 and hide collapsed row's border and also hide previous or next row's top or bottom border and then it looks good. Is there simpler solution?

Comment: I had to add `padding:0` to completely remove vertical space (using with bootstrap css).

Comment: For me it was
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
Set to table, td, th, tr,  ... grrr.

Answer (score -1):

use CSS:

```
tr {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, see my edit. By hidden from view, I mean completely disappear. Unfortunately, `visibility: hidden;` leaves a gap in the table, which is undesirable.